# Question about Chebyshev Polynomials in Beardon

Tags: trigonometry, dynamical-systems

I happen to be reading through Beardon's book, *Iteration of Rational Functions*, and I have come across a statement I don't quite believe. He uses it a little later on, so I'm concerned with clearing it up before I move on. First he makes the definition

$$
T_k(\cos (x)) = \cos (kx).
$$

This is fine, this is the usual definition. But then he states that from this, we can see

$$
(T_k)^n(x) = \cos (k^n x).
$$

This is what I'm having trouble seeing. For example, I know

\begin{align}
T_2(\cos (x)) &= \cos (2x) = 2 \cos^2(x) -1\\
T_4(\cos (x)) &= \cos (4x) = 8\cos^4(x)-8\cos^2(x)+1.
\end{align}

Using these identities, then according to his formula

$$
(T_2)^2(\cos (x)) = \cos (4x).
$$

But it is easily seen that

$$
(T_2)^2(\cos (x)) = (2 \cos^2(x)-1))^2 = 4\cos^4(x)-4\cos^2(x)+1,
$$
while

$$
\cos(4x) = 8\cos^4(x)-8\cos^2(x)+1.
$$

Can someone clarify for me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If $(T_k)^n$ means composition: $T_k\circ T_k\circ\dots\circ T_k$, then it's ok, since, for example, $T_k(T_k(\cos x))=T_k(\cos kx)=\cos k^2x$, and more generally, $T_p\circ T_q=T_{pq}$.

Comment: Yes I believe you are correct. I started the book a few months ago, and had forgotten about his prerequisites section where he makes mention of this. Thank you Jean-Claude.